# Insert a custom field into a shortcode and use it in post(s)

Tags: custom-field, shortcode

I would like to insert a custom field into a shortcode and use it in post(s). I want the shortcode to be used with parameters. I tried to solve this problem but it displays the "Array" word instead of the value of the custom field:

```
function get_my_custom_field( $atts ) {
    global $post;
    return get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field, true );
}
add_shortcode( 'insert-custom-field', 'get_my_custom_field' );
```

The shortcode present in the post:

```
[insert-custom-field field="price"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already stated in comments, `extract()` should never be used. It was removed from core and the codex for very specific reasons and the use there of is strictly not recommended in future applications and functions. Please [see trac ticket #22400](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22400) for complete details.

As stated before, the codex was also updated accordingly, so you can look at the examples given in the [Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) on how to construct a proper shortcode.

With this all in mind, you can create your shortcode as follows:

```
function get_my_custom_field( $atts ) {
    $attributes = shortcode_atts( array(
        'field' => '';
    ), $atts );

    global $post;

    if ( empty( $attributes['field'] ) )
      return null;

    return get_post_meta( $post->ID, $attributes['field'], true );
}
add_shortcode( 'insert-custom-field', 'get_my_custom_field' );
```

### EDIT

You will maybe want to sanitize the input as well according to your input. I will leave that up to you as I'm not exactly sure which data will be passed

Comment: O crap, thanks for pointing that out. Slipped there.

Answer (score -1):

The `$atts` don't extract automatic, try this before call `global $post`

```
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'field' => '',//#Default value or null
  ), $atts));
```

This code extract `$atts` to single variables, see more in [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode).

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but I think you have missed that very same page in the codex. Never ever use use `extract()`. It was removed from core and the codex for specific reasons. Please recheck and reread the page that you have linked to in the codex and learn how a proper shortcode should look like without using `extract()`